# Traversing an ArrayList with an Iterator and setting an object with instanceof

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

I have an ArrayList of objects and an iterator that traverses them. I'm trying to find the instance of the Ant object in the list and assign it to the ant variable.

```
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    if(iterator.getNext() instanceof Ant) {
        Ant ant = (Ant)iterator.getNext();
    }
}
```

Since iterator.getNext() increments the iterator when called, the above code assigns the object after the ant to the ant variable. I was wondering how I could correctly assign the Ant object in the list to the ant variable.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `.getNext()` twice so you are actually casting the object after the one you are checking.

Try this:

```
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
  Object obj = iterator.next();
  if (obj instanceof Ant) {
    Ant ant = (Ant)obj;
  }
}
```

Also it should be noted that it is `.next()` not `.getNext()` to retrieve the underlying object in the iterator.

Answer (score -1):

It occurs because you call `iterator.getNext()` twice: first time at condition and then in condition body, so you missed first value and try second to Ant type. You need code like

```
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            Object obj = null; 
            if((obj = iterator.getNext()) instanceof Ant) {
                Ant ant = (Ant)obj;
            }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate answer of https://stackoverflow.com/a/58495096/5221149, which has valid code (method `getNext()` is undefined), and more readable code that doesn't use inline assignment.